# Question concerning about dual space, weak convergence and weak* convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $X$ a separable normed space, we know that every bounded sequence $(f_n)$ in $X^*$ has a weak*-convergent subsequence.

My first question is: when will it have a weak convergent subsequence? Can this only happen in finite dimensional space?

My second question is: Can we say a dual space is "complete" in the sense that every Cauchy sequence has a weak*-convergent subsequence? If yes, is it possible to extend to that every Cauchy sequence has a weak-convergent subsequence, and finally every Cauchy sequence has a norm-convergent subsequence?

Comment: What do you mean by Cauchy sequence here? Because in the usual sense being Cauchy in a Banach space $Y$ is equivalent to norm convergence. Because $Y= X^*$ is a Banach space, it is trivial that every Cauchy sequence in $X^*$ has a norm-convergent subsequence since the sequence itself is convergent.

Comment: Bounded nets have weak* convergent subnets; what you wrote about sequences may not hold.

Comment: @Demophilus My thought is that, completeness sort of likes sequences have limit. We know that w* convergent doesn't imply w convergent, hence my question is asking like whether or not we can extend the space to a bigger space so that the sequence which previously doesn't have w limit now can have w limit

Comment: My question was only about this part of the question "finally every Cauchy sequence has a norm-convergent subsequence?". If you consider Cauchy sequences to be defined in terms of the norm, then that would be trivial. You can also define a sequence to be Cauchy with respect to another topological vector space, but then my question is with respect to what topology?
You should also consider @DavidMitra comment, compactness doesn't necessarily imply sequential compactness.